# Why does my NSToolbar not get the icon/text/icon+text options?

Tags: macos, appkit, nstoolbar

I have an NSToolbar with some items in it.  In most NSToolbars on macOS, when you right-click, you get the choice of icon, text, or icon+text.  These 3 choices also appear as a popup menu, in the bottom-left corner of the Customize sheet.

In my app, I don't get this.  Instead, in the context menu, I get the option "Use Small Size".  In the customization panel, instead of the popup menu, I have a (terribly placed!) checkbox, "Use small size".

What causes an NSToolbar to get "Use small size", rather than the icon/text/icon+text choices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you by any chance doing `[self.window setTitleVisibility:NSWindowTitleHidden];` to move the toolbar up into the title bar area?

If that's the case, toolbars are limited to icons only in this case.